# How score chi-square is computed in stepwise selection

Tags: statistics, sas, logistic-regression

In SAS stepwise selection, features are selected by the max score chi-square value, it first trains a model with all the variable except the intercept, and then compute the score test for every feature, I don't understand how the score chi-square is computed

Comment: Please ask statistics questions on Cross Validated. Also please remember the requirement to include a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example with code and data.

Comment: Check the details section of the proc you're using - which you haven't specified.

Comment: Second last paragraph here, links to references: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_details11.htm